# 406 Not Acceptable on MacOSX Maverick

Tags: osx-mavericks, http-status-code-406

I am really new for Mac OSX, I had develop the web based application while communicate with another server.
Tried before on Linux, the scripts works well, but when I tried to implemented on Mac OSX server I got the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
```

Tried using .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

and this:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

I tried to testing this on Linux environtment, and works.
Anyone know how to fix this on Mac?

Thanks

Comment: I think no one has faced this problem?